# How to cache images when using imageWithData to make a UIImage

Tags: ios, ios5, image-caching, imagenamed

I'm downloading and saving some images from the web into my app's private storage to be displayed in tableview cells. I have it working, but unfortunately unless I'm using :

```
[UIImage imageNamed: @"filename"];
```

I don't get the built-in cache, and performance is slow. How can I implement my own image cache when using `imageWithData` or `imageWithContentsOfFile`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've seen more then a few discussions of this online over the years with various solutions and rationales. Arguably the simplest solution is [here](http://www.alexcurylo.com/blog/2009/01/13/imagenamed-is-evil/).

In short with large numbers of images, `UIImage imageNamed` is rough on memory and it suggests using a simple dictionary with `imageWithContentsOfFile` to store cached images where you can easily have more control over memory usage.

Comment: Also worth noting, there are several good libraries that also solve this issue if you ever run into cases that actually need something more complicated.

Comment: any in mind? My problem now is that while it cache's the images, whe neach cell is made there is a slight lag which AFNetworking avoids, but i need better cache management then what AFNetworking offers.